# Adding dynamic path between components in SSIS

Tags: c#-4.0, ssis

I am trying to create a ssis package in c#. As I am new to C# and SSIS, i am facing an issue,when more than one transformation component is added.I am using a metadata file to get the values for components.But, i am not able to create a dynamic path between components.Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "create a dynamic path between components" ?

Comment: You're new to C# *and* SSIS and your trying to build packages? Keep this site on your bookmarks, you're in for a bumpy ride.

Comment: it will be bumpy but enjoyable :-)

Comment: Outside the 5 minute window for edits, but the reason for my comment is that learning one new language is probably going to be enough to keep you occupied but adding in the quirky object model for SSIS and the COM parts of the data model which means learning how to deal with that too, it's a bit more than I'd want to bite off. Plus, C# processing is generally different than optimal SSIS processing (for *each row*, do this vs for this *set* of data, do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use global variable and pass it thro diff component of ssis